# Drop in Amplifier High Frequency Gain without Large Power Capacitors

Tags: amplifier, resonance

I have designed a simple class AB audio amplifier circuit which can be seen below. [image: Class AB Audio Amplifier]

I am simulating the amplifier and have used a single, 100uF capacitor for C3 and C4. The simulation is being run with a non-ideal voltage supply. When using an ideal supply with Vcc = 20V and Vee = -20V, the following issues do not occur.

However, with this value for these power capacitors, and a non-ideal supply, I have a large dip in my output voltage gain from around 10 kHz to 20 kHz. This dip decreases as I increase C3/C4. The amplifier is connected to an 8 ohm load.

[[image: Output Voltage with C3 = C4 = 100uF][2]]

[image: Output Voltage with C3 = C4 = 1000uF]

Here is the ngspice model for the non-ideal PSU:

```
.subckt psudc dcplus dcminus psugnd


* ---- CURRENT-LIMITED BENCH PSU -------
* Positive output  20 V at node (5)1000
* Negative output -20 V at node (5)2000
* Current-limited supply - output voltages drop if I-limit exceeded

IsourceVCC  psugnd 1001   3.0 
RsourceVCC  1001   psugnd 100k
DsourceVCC  1001   1002   D1
VsourceVCC  1002   1003   19.2
Rsource2VCC 1003   psugnd 1m   
IsourceVEE  2001   psugnd 3.0 
RsourceVEE  2001   psugnd 100k
DsourceVEE  2002   2001   D1
VsourceVEE  2002   2003  -19.2
Rsource2VEE 2003   psugnd 1m   
RcableVCC   1001   1004   20m
RcableVEE   2001   2004   20m

* Measure
VcurrentVCC 1004   1005  DC   0
VcurrentVEE 2004   2005  DC   0

* Output
LsourceVCC  1005   dcplus   1u
LsourceVEE  2005   dcminus  1u

.ends
```

The current limit, however, is nowhere close to being exceeded.

The problem seems to be completely removed if use massive capacitors e.g. 1F. What could be causing this can how could it be solved?

Comment: Q7 seems to be wired incorrectly, to me. But I don't know what's driving it, either. And I'm guessing that Q5 is supposed to be a current source. Q6 is obviously your vbe-multiplier. Could you write a little more about your thinking process in this design and what may be in the circuitry behind it that I cannot see? Also, did you consider bootstrapping to avoid Q5?

Comment: Also, are you looking to achieve about 3 W output into 8 Ohms? Or what's your spec here?

Comment: If it's not clear enough, I'm wondering why you aren't doing something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyUp3.png). Took me a moment to pony it up. But, without sitting down to calculate specific values in some depth, that's about what I'm thinking.

Comment: One thing I don't see is any negative feedback. Is that absent or just not shown in the schematic?

Comment: @jonk this is a university project. The layout and design is mostly fixed. In fact, I built the amplifier and successfully got > 8Wrms output @ 1khZ. Q7 is a current sink transistor.

Comment: @GodJihyo what type of negative feedback? This circuit here is the entire schematic, excluding the preamp.

Comment: @GaryAllen Usually there would be feedback from the output to one of the earlier stages. This reduces distortion, widens the frequency response, stabilizes the gain, and lowers the output impedance. It's common to use a differential input stage and return the feedback to the inverting input, pretty much like a high power op-amp.

Comment: @GaryAllen If this layout and design is mostly fixed, what did you mean when writing, *"I have designed a..."*?

Comment: @jonk I meant that I calculated and chose all resistor and capacitor values, as well as added one or two components (stability resistors RF, potentiometers etc.) I am only a student so this is what we refer to as "design" at least at the moment.

Comment: @GaryAllen I'm missing seeing your design process, then. How did you calculate values? What values did you calculate? (It's nice to see that you were provided with a PSU model! That was the right thing to also do.) The topology alone won't help us tell you what capacitor values to use. (Or, at least *I* don't think it will.)

Comment: @jonk I've realized the dip is due to the resonant frequency of the power supply - power capacitor combination. The dip occurs at \$f_0 = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(L_{supply}*C_{bypass}))\$. In my case, \$L_{supply} = 1uH\$ and \$C_{bypass} = 100uF\$. How would this be prevented?

Comment: @GaryAllen I didn't think it rude, at all. I just responded to your comment with a question. But yes, I think you should seek help elsewhere, now. A an